# Extending $L^{p}$ Duality to $\sigma$-finite Spaces

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $1 \leq p < \infty$, $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a sigma-finite measure space. Let $L$ be a continuous linear form on $L^{p}(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$. Then, show that $\exists g \in L^{p'}$ such that:

$L(f)=\displaystyle\int fg d\mu \quad \forall f \in L^{p}(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$

---

I have shown the result for the underlying space being a finite measure space. If our space is sigma finite, then we can find an increasing sequence of sets $(X_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ for the $X_{n}$s having finite measure.

I was thinking of restricting ourselves to a $X_{n}$ and then finiding $g_{n} \in L^{p'}(X_{n}, \mathcal{M}_{n}, \mu)$, for $g_{n}$ having $L^{p'}$ norm smaller than the operator norm of $L$ and $L(f)=\int fg_{n} d\mu$, $\forall f \in L^{p}(X_{n},\mathcal{M}_{n},\mu)$ as we have shown the result for finite measure spaces.

However, what would be the way to use the above observation to extend the result to $X$? (and finding the appropriate $g \in L^{p}(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ such that we have the result). On the other hand, this might seem like a silly question, but how does one use this result to show that the dual space of $L^{p}$ is isomorphic to $L^{p'}$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show that $g_m|X_n = g_n$ for $m > n$. Then it should be clear how to define $g$ (pointwise limit). Second question: Show that $\|L\| = \|g\|_{L^{p'}}$. Then $\Phi : L^{p'}\to (L^p)^*$, $\Phi(g)f = \int fg\,d\mu$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'm kind of stumped on how to show $g_{m}|X_{n}=g_{n}$ though, is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Let $g := g_n - g_m$ on $X_n$ and choose $f : X_n\to\mathbb C$ by $f = \chi_{\{|g|>1/k\}}\frac{\overline{g}}{|g|^2}$.Then $\mu(\{|g_n-g_m|>1/k\}) = \int_{X_n}f(g_n-g_m)\,d\mu = L(f)-L(f) = 0$.